# Split comma delimited string --> FUNCTION db.CHARINDEX does not exist

Tags: mysql, string, function, split

I need to split comma delimited string into a second columns 
I have the following table :

```
CL1     POS                 POS2     LENGHT     ALLELE
1       3015108,3015109              5          A
2       3015110,3015200              10         B
3       3015200,3015300              15         C
4       3015450,3015500              20         D
5       3015600,3015700              15         E
```

I want to split the numbers after the comma into a second column POS2
So it should like that

```
CL1     POS                 POS2     LENGHT     ALLELE
1       3015108             3015109  5          A
2       3015110             3015200  10         B
3       3015200             3015300  15         C
4       3015450             3015500  20         D
5       3015600             3015700  15         E
```

So I've queried the following :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (POS2)
SELECT RIGHT(POS, CHARINDEX(',', POS) + 1 ) FROM MyTable ;


 It returns an error : 
 ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION test.CHARINDEX does not exist
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a built-in `CHARINDEX()` function. [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) would be the MySQL equivalent.

Using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) might be a more succinct way of doing this. Something like this (disclaimer: untested):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(POS, ',', 1)` for POS

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(POS, ',', -1)` for POS2

---

As an aside, I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you might want to `UPDATE` existing rows, not `INSERT` new ones? Something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET POS2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(POS, ',', -1);
UPDATE MyTable SET POS = SUBSTRING_INDEX(POS, ',', 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

`MySQL` does have a similar function: `InStr` or for the same syntax Locate.