# MySql Procedure values for insert as a variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some trouble with MySql Procedure. 
I have:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees2`;
CREATE TABLE `employees2` (
  `LastName` varchar(20) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `FirstName` varchar(10) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It work's and is OK.

And MySQL Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS gen;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE gen()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE e1 TEXT;
        DECLARE e2 TEXT;
        DECLARE e3 TEXT;
        SET e1 = "Davolio";
        SET e2 = "Nancy";
        SET e3 = "Ron , Deplin";
        insert  into `employees2`(`LastName`,`FirstName`) values ('Nonew','adams');
        insert  into `employees2`(`LastName`,`FirstName`) values (e1,e2);
        insert  into `employees2`(`LastName`,`FirstName`) values (e3);

    END $$
DELIMITER ;

call gen();
```

I would like to instert into table values from variable e3. "Ron" is for column `LastName` and "Deplin" is for column FirstName. But i got error: "Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" First and second inserts works fine. How to force the third insert to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You're only specifying one value with two columns named in your last insert, hence the unequal row count.

See this post on how to use MySQL to split a string like that got two value entries:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953163/2812842

Comment: Yes. 
But i have:
SET e3 = "Ron , Deplin";
And Ron is for `LastName` column and Deplin is for `FirstName`column. I just would like paste this e3 between () in insert query.

Comment: Ok. 
`insert  into `employees2`(`LastName`,`FirstName`) values (SUBSTRING_INDEX(e3, ',',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(e3, ',',-1));`
It's works but it's not what i want. When i will have longer list of values this method will be useless.

Comment: Do you need to split a string like that? The more data you have, the more you should be using separate fields or structured data...

Comment: OK. But what if:
insert  into `employees2`(`LastName`,`FirstName`,`City`,`Country`) values (e1,e2);
where my e1 = "Ron , Deplin" and e2 = "NY, USA"
I tried change e3 on many ways and it did not pass. For example:
e3 = "'Ron' , 'Deplin'" etc
@scrowler - maybe i'am not clear. Do you understood what im want to do ?