# SQL query to extract sentences from a paragraph

Tags: mysql, sql, extract, paragraph, sentence

I am creating an SQL query that will produce a CSV output. I need to extract sentences from a paragraph in the database and set them up as separate fields in the CSV output.

My example paragraph is as below;

> "A stunning mock twinset top  with 3/4 length sleeves. Features a wave
>   textured mock insert with a plain contrast outer fabric. Two pleats to
>   each shoulder add drape to this versatile top."

I need to break it up so that my SQL query looks something like this;

> 'A stunning mock twinset top  with 3/4 length sleeves' AS 'point1'
>   'Features a wave textured mock insert with a plain contrast outer
>   fabric' AS 'point2' 'Two pleats to each shoulder add drape to this
>   versatile top' AS 'point3'

and so on until the end of the paragraph. All the sentences in the paragraph end with a full-stop so I could use this in the 'CASE' statement but not sure how.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Although possible, this isn't really a task for MySQL

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry You should consider in using a NLP tool such as  [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) and train a proper model to use the SentenceDetector Tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split comma delimited string --> FUNCTION db.CHARINDEX does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953114/split-comma-delimited-string-function-db-charindex-does-not-exist)

Comment: Will you have a separate record on your table for each paragraph, and if so, do you know the maximum number of sentences you will have in each paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of sentences you're going to have in a paragraph (and assuming you have a separate record for each paragraph) then you could split your paragraph like this:

```
select substring_index(paragraph,'.',1) as point1, 
       ltrim(substring_index(substring_index(paragraph,'.',2),'.',-1)) as point2,
       ltrim(substring_index(substring_index(paragraph,'.',3),'.',-1)) as point3,
       ltrim(substring_index(substring_index(paragraph,'.',4),'.',-1)) as point4,
...
from my_table
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Brilliant. I was able to sort my script out. This was basically for creating an Amazon Flat File for clothing. In your script I replaced the words 'paragraph' with my table I needed to pick the data for example; 

substring_index(MyTable.RequiredColumn,'.',1) as 'bullet_point1',