# Remove all characters after a period in SQL

Tags: sql

I am querying a table/column that has results like this:

```
abc.1234  
abcdef.123  
ab.12345
```

I query it like:

```
Select
Program.fullname as "Full Name"
```

I want to only return the `abc, abcdef, ab`.
Having trouble figuring out how to do so (even though I suspect it should be simple)

When I run:

instr(Program.fullname) as "Full Name" , it only returns the index of the period. What do I need to add to get the actual string before the period?

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: I'm using Squirrel SQL

Comment: Squirel SQL is a client that enables you to connect to a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split comma delimited string --> FUNCTION db.CHARINDEX does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953114/split-comma-delimited-string-function-db-charindex-does-not-exist)

Comment: What DBMS you're using?

Comment: So when I use INSTR, it only returns a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substr(Program.fullname, 1, instr(Program.fullname,'.')-1) as "Full Name"

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql, this works

```
Select
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Program.fullname, '.', 1)  as "Full Name"
```