# How to Split string by space in sql

Tags: mysql, split

I need to split space delimited string :

```
myTable.myColumn
'KR11 KN22 M33 CH44'
```

I was try this code below

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',myColumn) = 0
```

but It returns an error :

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION myDB.CHARINDEX does not exist
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953114/split-comma-delimited-string-function-db-charindex-does-not-exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the name string in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.